# Create borders around each series of duplicates in my sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an incredibly large sheet with necessary groups of duplicate items in a column.

To make it easier to read I want to put borders around each series of duplicates. Let's say A1 through A5 all say Banana, I want to border this.

I am able to identify duplicates and border them but I'm lost when I try to identify first duplicate then last duplicate and border the whole group.

Comment: Are all values for (eg) Banana grouped together, or could there be multiple groups of the same item?

Comment: Ah! Good question, I suppose this makes it easier. Each group only repeats once and they are already grouped together, so you could say the duplicates themselves are actually unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a sample code here is the syntax to apply a boarder to a range of cells at once using the [Range.BoarderAround method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borderaround):

```
Sub ApplyBoarderToRangeTest()

Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C10")

TargetRange.BorderAround xlContinuous, xlMedium     'xlContinuous = 1, xlMedium = -4138 for late binding

'Now cells C2 to C10 have a medium weight continuous boarder around them.

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this is definitely very helpful for what I aiming for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim r As Long, m As Long
m = 1
For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(r, 1).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 1).Value Then Range("A" & m & ":A" & r).BorderAround , xlMedium: m = r + 1
Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Worked great, really clever way to handle it.